# Pass generic function and its parameters to meta-function

Tags: c++

First of all, I feel like this must have been asked already somewhere, but all my searches proved fruitless. If this is indeed a duplicate of something somewhere, I apologize in advance.

I am trying to mass-benchmark a bunch of functions from OpenCV and to do so I wanted to write a small meta-function that takes the function to run, its parameters (which vary according to the function passed) and essentially sets up the timing and runs the function in a loop.

Since I'm planning to pass lambdas to the meta-function as well later on (to benchmark composition of functions), I thought of using `std::function`.

This is the code I came up with after reading [the parameter pack description](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack):

```
template<typename ...Ts> 
void run_test(std::string test_name, int num_repeats, std::function<void(Ts...)> f, Ts... fargs)
{
    std::cout << std::endl << "Starting " << test_name << std::endl;
    start_timing(test_name);
    for(int i=0; i<num_repeats; i++)
    {
        f(fargs...);
    }
    end_timing(num_repeats);
}
```

As you see, functionality is down to a minimum. `start_timing` and `end_timing` are simple helper functions beyond the scope of this question.

In my main, I call:

```
// im_in defined and loaded elsewhere
cv::Mat out(im_in.size(), CV_8U);
run_test(
    "erode 3x3",
    100,
    cv::erode,
    im_in, out, cv::Mat::ones(3,3,CV_8U)
);
```

Now, if I try to compile this, I get:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'run_test(const char [10], const int&, void (&)(cv::InputArray, cv::OutputArray, cv::InputArray, cv::Point, int, int, const Scalar&), cv::Mat&, cv::Mat&, cv::MatExpr)'
  );
  ^
note: candidate: template<class ... Ts> void run_test(std::__cxx11::string, int, std::function<void(Ts ...)>, Ts ...)
 void run_test(std::string test_name, int num_repeats, std::function<void(Ts...)> f, Ts... fargs)
      ^~~~~~~~
note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
note:   mismatched types 'std::function<void(Ts ...)>' and 'void (*)(cv::InputArray, cv::OutputArray, cv::InputArray, cv::Point, int, int, const Scalar&) {aka void (*)(const cv::_InputArray&, const cv::_OutputArray&, const cv::_InputArray&, cv::Point_<int>, int, int, const cv::Scalar_<double>&)}'
  );
```

So... what am I doing wrong? Why is it having a type mismatch instead of deducing the types in `Ts...` from the parameters list as I expected?

---

#### Update:

After writing the last question above, I realized it might have problems deducing `Ts...` for the `std::function` because the parameter comes before the actual parameter list to expand into `Ts...`. So, I changed my code as follows (essentialy, I moved the `f` parameter at the end):

```
void run_test(std::string test_name, int num_repeats, Ts... fargs, std::function<void(Ts...)> f)
{ ... }
```

Of course, I also adapted the function call accordingly:

```
cv::Mat out(im_in.size(), CV_8U);
run_test(
    "erode 3x3",
    NUM_REPEATS,
    im_in, out, cv::Mat::ones(3,3,CV_8U),
    cv::erode, // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
);
```

Now, if I compile, I get a different error:

```
error: expected primary-expression before ')' token );
```

The change in error makes me think the order of the parameters was indeed important. Is, however, this the correct one? If so, what am I doing wrong?

---

#### Update2:

Writing the first update, it struck me that probably my assumption that `f` can take a function and convert it to a `std::function` was probably wrong. After a quick research, it seems it is.

I tried replacing `std::function<void(Ts...)> f` with both `auto f` and `auto& f` (& compiling with C++14 enabled), but the `expected primary-expression` error is still there.

For all I could research, I couldn't find a way that allows me to just pass the function relying on the compiler to figure out the types.
I'm thinking of adapting C++17's `std::apply` function implementation shown [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/apply) adding my timing loop around the `invoke` call, but I don't understand that code, so the chance of getting something wrong is high.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might get rid of `std::function` (which add overhead BTW), and use generic for `f` too:

```
template<typename F, typename ...Ts> 
void run_test(std::string test_name, int num_repeats, F f, const Ts&... fargs)
{
    std::cout << std::endl << "Starting " << test_name << std::endl;
    start_timing(test_name);
    for(int i=0; i<num_repeats; i++)
    {
        f(fargs...);
    }
    end_timing(num_repeats);
}
```

> I realized it might have problems deducing Ts... for the std::function

As `cv::erode` is not a `std::function`, `Ts...` cannot be deduced from it, but would be from extra parameters.

Your problem is that `cv::erode` has extra (defaulted) parameters.
so you cannot create the `std::function<Ts...>` with `Ts...` deduced from parameters.

To bypass that issue, you might use lambda instead:

```
run_test(
    "erode 3x3",
    100,
    [&](){ cv::erode(im_in, out, cv::Mat::ones(3,3,CV_8U)); }
);
```

Comment: receiving argument as `const Ts&` change properties of the parameters

Comment: As it is for profiling/timing, I expect to not change given arguments.

Comment: it can lead to changes in overload resolutions, and speed can change between a copy and a move

Comment: Is there a reason for the const? I'll pass as argument the output cv::Mat to be written into by the function, so that can't be const

Comment: @GPhilo: you might use `Ts&&` instead of `const Ts&` to allow both reference and temporary. Calling with `std::ref(my_arg)` would be an other alternative.

Comment: Wouldn't it be sufficient to use `Ts&`?

Comment: You wont get temporary unfortunately.

Comment: And are there any shortcomings to use &&? (Like, objects accidentally ending up moved or similar). I still don't get completely the & vs && parameter distinction.

Comment: @GPhilo: In this situation, I would say that the correct code uses `T&&.. args` and then calls `f(std::forward<T>(args)...)`. Explaining exactly how that works is a bit hard, but you can google "perfcet forwarding". That relies on `&&`, deduced template types, and `std::forward<>`. It's carefully designed to forward the arguments from the wrapper to a wrapped function. Just follow the exact pattern when you need the forwarding.

Comment: Thanks, after adapting your code with the Ts&& and fixing the function call, it now finally compiles. I had, however, to pass all parameters of `erode`, even the default ones. Is this necessary or is there a way to have it keep the default parameter values without having to specify them?

Comment: Thanks, that actually seems to solve the whole "pass sub-function parameters down" problem too

Comment: I'm trying to think if the lambda approach could have drawbacks I'm not aware of, but so far it looks like the simplest and cleanest solution (and it doesn't require `std::forward` or parameter packs)

Comment: @MSalters forwarding the same values multiple times is incorrect in the case of the parameters which get modified when moved from

Answer (score 3):

the error `expected primary-expression before ')'` is because you left a `,` after your last parameter

parameter pack must always be the last parameters of a functions

you should probably try this

```
template<typename Callable, typename ...Ts> 
void run_test(std::string test_name, int num_repeats, Callable func, Ts&& ... fargs)
{
    std::cout << std::endl << "Starting " << test_name << std::endl;
    start_timing(test_name);
    for(int i=0; i<num_repeats; i++)
    {
        func(std::forward<Ts>(fargs)...);
    }
    end_timing(num_repeats);
}
```

Comment: It might be "dangerous" to forward several times the **same** argument (with `std::unique_ptr`, next calls will "receive" `nullptr`).

Comment: @Jarod42: That's a rather unavoidable problem. Functions that take a `std::unique_ptr<T>` consume a T. Somehow the `runt_test` method would need to create `num_repeats-1` extra T objects, without knowing anything about T.

Comment: @MSalters Yes, but at least the non-forwarding version alerts you to the problem by failing to compile when it tries to copy uncopyable things, rather than silently changing the behaviour of `num_repeats-1` calls